# Using PyQt4, how do you set a mouseMoveEvent to only work inside of a QWidget in a QMainWindow but not in the MainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt4

My current code below works for updating the x-y coordinates in 2 textBrowsers in my MainWindow, but it doesn't work when the cursor is inside of the textBrowsers.

For this example, I want the coordinates to ONLY update when the cursor is moving inside of textBrowser_1 and nowhere else.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(800, 132)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_1 = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser_1)
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


class MyMainScreen(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()  # This is from a python export from QtDesigner
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.ui.textBrowser_1.installEventFilter(self)
        # self.ui.textBrowser_1.setMouseTracking(True)
        # self.ui.menubar.setMouseTracking(True)
        # self.ui.statusbar.setMouseTracking(True)

    def setMouseTracking(self, flag):
        def recursive_set(parent):
            for child in parent.findChildren(QtCore.QObject):
                try:
                    child.setMouseTracking(flag)
                except:
                    pass
                recursive_set(child)
        QtGui.QWidget.setMouseTracking(self, flag)
        recursive_set(self)



    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.ui.textBrowser_1.setText(str(event.x()))
        self.ui.textBrowser_2.setText(str(event.y()))
        QtGui.QMainWindow.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainscreen = MyMainScreen()
    mainscreen.show()
    app.exec_()
```

This is what the program looks like:
[mouseTest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFAKT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code example, it looks like you may have already tried an event-filter, but that is probably the best solution. The trick is to install it on the [viewport](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewport) of the widget (if it has one):

```
class MyMainScreen(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.textBrowser_1.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.ui.textBrowser_1.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:
            self.ui.textBrowser_1.setText(str(event.x()))
            self.ui.textBrowser_2.setText(str(event.y()))
        return QtGui.QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, source, event)
```

Comment: I'm using QtDesigner and QAbstractScrollArea isn't an option. QScrollArea is, but it is used for adding a scroll wheel which I don't want. Since QAbstractScrollArea inherits from QFrame, I tried using a QFrame as a child of my widget, and called installEventFilter on that frame, but that did not work.

Comment: @ZachG. You have misunderstood. You do not need to change anything in Qt Designer. The code in my answer works perfectly fine as it is. Take the example code in your question and replace the `MyMainScreen` class with the one in my answer. Then everything will work exactly as you asked.

Comment: Awesome, so that works for QTextBrowers, but in my actual implementation I'm using a QWidget, but I figured it out! I had to use the QWidget.canvas.installEventFilter(self) and it works!!